# Jquery detect the main parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery

My problem that i am having is i want to get the parent id form a click within it. The problem comes when i have stacks of divs like as follows:

```
<div id="files">
<div id="F1"><span>Label</span></div>
<div id="F2"><span>Label</span></div>
<div id="F3"><span>Label</span></div>
<div id="F4"><span>Label</span></div>
</div>
```

I have the script to the point that if I click the F# div areas it will refer to its parent which is files, but if I was to click the label span, it would refer back to its parent with the is of the id F#. I basically need it to the point that if there is a click within the files div, I can get the id even though no exposed area of that div is showing.

The jquery I was using was this:

```
$(window).load(function(){

    $(document).bind("contextmenu", function(event) { 
        event.preventDefault();

        var pid = event.target.parentNode.id;
        var id = event.target.id;
        //$(pid).val().substring(0,4)
        $(this).parent();
        //alert((pid).val().substring(0,4));
        var pid = (pid).substring(0,6);    

        if(pid === "files" || pid === "filess" || pid === "folder"){
             $("<div class='custom-menu'>
                  <a onclick='fileHide()'>Open</a>
                  <br/>
                  <a onclick='newFile()'>Rename</a>
                  <br/>
                  <a href='#'>Share Folder</a>
                  <br/>
                  <a onclick='deleteFile(\""+ id +"\")'>Delete</a>
                </div>").appendTo("body")
                        .css({top: event.pageY + "px", left: event.pageX + "px"});
        }else{
             $("<div class='custom-menu'>
                  <a onclick='fileHide()'>Upload</a>
                  <br/>
                  <a onclick='newFile()'>New Folder</a>
                  <br/><a href='#'>Share Folders</a>
                  <br/><a href='#'>Deleted files</a>
                </div>").appendTo("body")
                        .css({top: event.pageY + "px", left: event.pageX + "px"});
        }

    }).bind("mouseup", function(event) {
        $("div.custom-menu").hide();
    });            
});
```

Comment: How are you attaching the event handler?

Comment: Just so you know, `var pid = event.target.parentNode.id;` is pure JavaScript, no jQuery at all here.

Comment: @acdcjunior: `$(event.target).parent().attr('id')` doesn't look much better.

Comment: This isn't the proper way to do whatever you're trying to do. Give those elements a class and attach a `contextmenu` event handler to them. Explicitly checking the `id` attribute of the parent element is unmaintainable.

Comment: updated the whole jquery/javascript section

Comment: @Blender Maybe so, but that's not the point. I wanted the OP to notice that one thing is not the other. Not knowing when something is "jQuery" and when something is pure JS is very common among beginners.

Comment: @acdcjunior I see a bunch of Jquery in there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
$(this).parent();
```

for each click on element call this,it will directly gives the parent of the selected(clicked) element

To know its id then try with

```
var parent_id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
alert(parent_id);
```

Comment: The event handler is bound to `document`, so `this` will be `document`.